# udpclient auto find server. client/broadcaster doesn't receive message

Tags: c#, .net, multicast, udpclient

I am trying to auto find server app within a local network using usbclient in the following code.
the sever and broadcaster is run on separate pc.
The server always receives the broadcaster message, but the broadcaster doesn't or sometimes receives message only once.

```
//////////////////////
// UDP BROADCASTER //
//////////////////////
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string addr = "224.0.0.1";
    const int prt = 5555;

    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient();
    udpc.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    var LocalIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
    Console.WriteLine($"LocalIP: {LocalIP}");

    udpc.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIP), prt));
    // Enable broadcast.
    udpc.EnableBroadcast = false;
    // Disable multicast loopback.
    udpc.MulticastLoopback = false;
    udpc.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(addr));
    System.Threading.ManualResetEvent abort = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    WaitHandle[] evs = new WaitHandle[2];
    evs[0] = abort;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IAsyncResult asy = udpc.BeginReceive(
            new AsyncCallback(delegate (IAsyncResult iasy)
            {
                IPEndPoint rp = null;
                byte[] recv = udpc.EndReceive(iasy, ref rp);
                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
                Console.WriteLine($"recv {data} from {rp.ToString()}");
            }), null);
            evs[1] = asy.AsyncWaitHandle;
            if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(evs) == 0) return;
        }
    }));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var msg = $"Hello {i}";
            var byts = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);//new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2 };
                udpc.Send(byts, byts.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(addr), prt));
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent: {msg}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (abort.WaitOne(0, false)) return;
        }
    }));
    Console.Read();
    abort.Set();
}
/////////////////
// UDP SERVER //
////////////////
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string addr = "224.0.0.1";
    const int prt = 5555;

    UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient();
    udpc.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    //udpc.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, prt));
    var LocalIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
    Console.WriteLine($"LocalIP: {LocalIP}");
    udpc.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIP), prt));
    udpc.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(addr));
    System.Threading.ManualResetEvent abort = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    WaitHandle[] evs = new WaitHandle[2];
    evs[0] = abort;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IAsyncResult asy = udpc.BeginReceive(
            new AsyncCallback(delegate (IAsyncResult iasy)
            {
                IPEndPoint rp = null;
                byte[] recv = udpc.EndReceive(iasy, ref rp);
                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv);
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay} recv {data} from {rp.ToString()}");
                var byts = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Ip:: {LocalIP} MachineName: {Environment.MachineName}");
                udpc.Send(byts, byts.Length, rp);

            }), null);
            evs[1] = asy.AsyncWaitHandle;
            if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(evs) == 0) return;
        }
    }));

    Console.Read();
    abort.Set();
}
```

any ideas or recommendation is welcome

Comment: _"but the broadcaster doesn't or sometimes receives message only once"_ - yep. UDP is unreliable by design. You _must_ anticipate missing packets, out-of-order packets and maybe even duplicate packets. Now, I don't know why you are not sending from a timer, simply, but alas. If A->B works more reliable than B->A, then there pretty probably should be a difference. Can you spot one?

Comment: no i cannot spot the error, pls point it out

Comment: :-) It was an honest question, I didn't mean to sound condescending. I was hoping you could point out a difference being "closer" to the code ... :)

Comment: What jumps to my eye (but may actually be valid): In your _broadcaster_ you have a comment `// Enable broadcast` and in the next line, you **disable** broadcasts ...

Comment: I faintly remember doing something similar (but in Java). I think, if I remember correctly, I had 2 Ports: Port A for Clients to trigger the Server to send a Beacon and Port B for the Clients to listen for that Beacon. So, Server would 1. Every X amount of time send a Beacon unconditionally ("KeepAlive") and 2. Upon receiving a trigger: a) stop listening for the trigger for X amount of time, b) would send out X number of Beacon packets, then after Y amount of time X/10 number of Beacons, then after Y*10 amount of time X/100 Beacons and after Y * 100 amount of time listen for triggers again.

Comment: Maybe also interesting for you: https://github.com/Yortw/RSSDP